# Sending data to $this->include view in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have separated my template for CodeIgniter 4 in to different parts like header ,footer & sidebar. I can include them in main view like

```
<?= $this->include('layouts/header') ?>
```

but I can't send the data to this layouts, I try following syntax as like sending data to view

```
<?= $this->include('layouts/header',['test'=>'hello']) ?>
```

but when I save and check that variable in layouts/header.php as `<?=$test?>`
It gives error
**ErrorException
Undefined variable: test**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `include` function comes out of `CodeIgniter\View\View` and its second parameter is an options array, not a data array:

```
/**
 * Used within layout views to include additional views.
 *
 * @param string     $view
 * @param array|null $options
 * @param null       $saveData
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function include(string $view, array $options = null, $saveData = true): string
{
    return $this->render($view, $options, $saveData);
}
```

`include` is meant to be used in conjunction with [View Layouts](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/view_layouts.html), which you've mentioned nothing about. If you just need the view as-is, you should just use what the `view` [function returns](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/views.html):

```
echo view('layouts/header',['test'=>'hello']);
```